# Debugging on a real BlackBerry device/simulator fails

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Hi I am trying to debug my app on a blackberry bold 9900. when I try to debug it on a real device eclipse throws an error saying "Could not get the debugger for jre6" and similarly when I try to debug on the simulator it throws an error saying "could not get the debugger for Blackberry JRE 7.1.0". Does anyone know how to sort this out?

Comment: which version of eclipse? which version of the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin (e.g. 1.5.0, 1.5.2)?  can you build a "Hello World" program, and run it on a simulator?

Comment: I am using Eclipse 1.5.2 and yeah the hello world did work. but i cant still run my previous project on the simulator

Answer (score 2):

The "jre6" message sounds like you're using the wrong runtime library in your debug configuration.

In Eclipse, right click on the project and go to `Debug As` -> `Debug configurations`. Then click on the `JRE` tab, ensure that you're using a BlackBerry `Runtime JRE`.